# Lambda not invoking if the uploaded files are large in size in s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have created a lambda which would invoke and do the transformation based on the event in the target source bucket.

This is working fine when I upload the small size of file in the targeted source bucket.

But when I upload large file(eg: `65 mb` file), it looks lambda not invoking based on that event..

Appreciate if anyone can help on this kind of issue?

Thanks

Comment: Are the large files stored in multi-part?

Comment: @umdev I am facing exactly the same problem. I tried it with specific event listeners and also with the global "s3:ObjectCreated" one. timetoupload 1 minute. Timeout of lambda 3 min. Also there was no invocation at all (according to CloudWatch). Can this be a bug in AWS?

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing, big files would be uploaded on S3 via [`S3 Multipart Upload`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html) instead of a regular [`put-object`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object.html) operation.

Maybe your Lambda function is just subscribed to `s3:ObjectCreated:Put` events. You need to add `s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload` permission to Lambda as well.

Answer (score 2):

The large files in S3 are uploaded via [S3 Multipart Upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html) instead of a regular PUT or single part upload process.

There can be two problems

1. ``In your lambda you probably have created the subscription for `s3:ObjectCreated:Put` events. You should add `s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload` too in the Lambda subscription list.
2. Your lambda timeout could be small for and that works for the smaller files. You might want to increase that.

Answer (score 2):

There could be any of these issues:

1. Your event only captures `s3:ObjectCreated:Put` event, as others have mentioned. Usually if it's a big file, the event is `s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload` instead. You could either:

   - add `s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload` event to your capture, or
   - simply use `s3:ObjectCreated:*` event - this will include Put, MultiPart Upload, Post, Copy, and also other similar events to be added in the future (source: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-event-notification/)
2. Your Lambda function might run longer limit you set (limit is 15min).
3. Your Lambda function requires more memory than the limit you set.
4. Your Lambda function requires more disk space than the limit you set. This may be an issue if your function downloads the data on disk first and perform transformation there (limit currently is 512MB).